# rich:calendar custom footer not being recognized

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I've having problems trying to customize the footer on a calendar using the `f:facet tag`. The content in the tag is being ignored, being the default footer shown instead.
I can customise the footer using `rich:calendar` attributes like `showApplyButton`, but I think it is not possible to remove the selected date that appears on the left of Clean button ('Netejar' in the image) without adding the Apply button, which is something my customer doesn't want.

We are using RichFaces 4.3.5.Final.

Code:

```
<rich:calendar
    value="#{YourBeanHere.yourDateHere}"
    locale="es_ES">
    <f:facet name="footer">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%" columnClasses="fake, width100 talign">
            <h:outputText value="{selectedDateControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
            <h:outputText value="{timeControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
            <h:outputText value="{todayControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>
</rich:calendar>
```

Calendar sample as it is shown with the code above:

[image: Calendar sample]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar footer is not customizable (not every component is set up to use the facets). You have to put the grid under the table and hide the footer (`.rf-cal-ftr`) if you need to.

Comment: I checked this website for the example: [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_calendar.html). Has been the facets support dropped for RF 4.3.5 (or 4.X.X)?

Comment: I'd assume so, since there is no mention of it in 4.0.X docs.